# join single value from one table to multiple rows table - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following tables in Oracle:

```
Table 1                Table 2
AllCustomers           ProductCode   Customers
5200000                ABC           15265
                       DEF           156890
```

In Oracle, I want to join them both, like this:

```
Table 3
ProductCode   Customers   AllCustomers           
ABC           15265       5200000
DEF           156890      5200000
```

How can I join these tables? As you can see, they do not have a key field to join. I just need to populate a third column in the new table with the same value in it, which would be the one from AllCustomers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you need if Table1 has more than one customer in it? (More than one row?) What you are requesting is called a Cartesian join and the Oracle syntax is `select * from table2 cross join table1` - but if Table 1 has multiple rows, the result will repeat Table 2 several times, once for each row in Table 1.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for your answer. Table 1 will always contain 1 row, so I think the cross join would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try `Cross join`

```
SELECT t2.*,t1.* 
FROM Table1 t1 CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your goal without a join, like so:

```
SELECT ProductCode, Customers, (SELECT AllCustomers FROM Table1 WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
FROM Table2
```

Comment: To "Join two tables" doesn't mean that Table 2 has one more column, and to "update" that table. The OP has explicitly labeled the result of the join as Table **3**. So - why an UPDATE?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "Table 3" part. I will update my answer. Thanks!